# getting $ undefined, even if I referenced the lib

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have referenced the JQuery library using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I even tried downloading the lib and put it locally in my project. But I am still getting a JS error, saying: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It points me to this line of code:

`$("#navn").val() = localStorage.getItem("navn");`

The strange thing, is that at the storeInfo() function, it doesn't complain, and it works as it should there.

How come it suddenly says that it JQuery is not referenced?

```
var navn = null;
var adr = null;
var city = null;

function storeInfo() {
    navn = $("#navn").val();
    alert("Works");
    localStorage.setItem("navn", navn);
}

if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

    if (localStorage.getItem("navn") !== "undefined" || localStorage.getItem("navn") !== null) {
        alert(localStorage.navn);
        $("#navn").val() = localStorage.getItem("navn");  <------ Problem is here
    }

} else {
    alert("Local storage ikke understøttet af din browser");
}
```

Comment: `$("#navn").val() = localStorage.getItem("navn");` - that line is wrong. `val()` takes an argument to set the `value` - you dont set the function of `val()` equal to another.

Comment: Maybe you are including the jQuery script *after* this one. And it doesn't complain in the function because it isn't yet executed.

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery before the `<script>` tag that contains this code?

Comment: Having the script tag in the wrong place would explain why it works in the function. The function doesn't get called until some later event happens, and by then jQuery has been loaded and `$` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

`val` is both a getter and a setter. When you execute `val()` it returns a value. You cannot assign the result of a function to something, thus the error. You want:

```
$("#navn").val(localStorage.getItem("navn"))
```

Also, as Barmar pointed out, check that jQuery is loaded correctly, and using the dom ready event:

```
$(function(){
  // code here
})
```

Comment: This is true, but shouldn't that be causing a different error? I get `Invalid lefthand side in assignment`.

Comment: I would say he has two problems in his code.  One of which is not defining `$ = jQuery` and the other is this answer.

Comment: @Barmar: It is possible as well that jQuery is not loaded. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

The problem was that I added the reference to JQuery libraray after the code is called. So I moved the reference to JQuery library on top, which solved it.